# Can “Community Wiki” become public domain?

Tags: support, community-wiki, licensing

What is the license of an answer marked community wiki?

It seems a normal answer is [CC-BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Seven_regularly_used_licenses), which can possibly not be kept for community wiki contributions, since the author becomes the community.

What's the exact status of community wiki answers license wise? Or asked otherwise, is it possible to make a post [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Zero_/_public_domain) even?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the license is no different than for other posts: CC BY SA, the specific version depending on the date of the revision.

You can see this by looking at the timeline (example: [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/927386/timeline)).

Posting on SE licenses the content under CC BY SA, but the author still owns the copyright to their content and is free to release it under additional licenses, including a public domain license. Some users specify alternative licenses for their posts in their profile (example: [Art of Code](https://stackexchange.com/users/3457374/artofcode)). You could include a note of additional licenses that apply to your post in the post itself but I think there’s a chance that it would be edited out (for the same reason that signatures are edited out). I have also seen copyright notices appear in the corner of images (example: [Chinese SE — How do I self-answer “What does this say?”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/36144)).